# How to save data from HTML form on mongodb using radio buttons and checkboxes

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, forms, radio-button

I have an HTML form and I need to save the inserted data on a mongo database. What I have difficulties is to save data inserted by radio button and ckeckboxes.

Here is my HTML code:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Foto:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="animal[foto]" placeholder="image url">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Animal:</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" name="animal[tipo]" type="radio" value="dog" > Dog</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" name="animal[tipo]" type="radio" value="cat"> Cat</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" name="animal[tipo]" type="radio" value="other"> Other:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="animal[tipo]" placeholder="Which?">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Gender:</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" name="animal[sexo]" type="radio" value="Male"> Male</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" name="animal[sexo]" type="radio" value="Female"> Female</label>
    </div>
```

How can I save what is select in radio btn?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the value from the radio buttons.
If you are using a `javascript` library like `jQuery`, it's very easy:

```
alert($('input[name=animal[tipo]]:checked').val());
```

This code will select the checked input with `animal[tipo]` name, and gets it's value. Simple isn't it?

Then you can save it as you normally do